# Django Error form submission

Tags: django

I have an app that let you create a profile.
One of my app feature is it's let you edit your name and upload a image.

The problem is the user cannot submit the image unless he type his name.How can I fix this page to make it so If the user submit an image but doesn't submit a name . He will still have his old name
or if he doesn't submit an image and changes his name . He will still have his old picture?

I tried adding blank=True and null = False , null = True but doesn't seem to do the job

My models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=False)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

My forms.py

```
 class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('image','name',)
```

My views.py

```
def Display(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:LoginRequest'))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PersonForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            person = Person.objects.get(user=request.user)
            person.image = form.cleaned_data['image']
            person.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            person.save() 
    return render(request,'edit.html',{'form': PersonForm()})
```

[image]

Comment: did you delete the database and sync again after you modified the name field?

Comment: @catherine nope okay i will do it now but catherine (max_length=100,null=True,blank=False) is right?

Comment: it's CharField so `(max_length=100, blank=True)`

Comment: @catherine I syncdb again . When I just add an image without a name . I got blank name

Comment: yes because you didn't define name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/", blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

def Display(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:LoginRequest'))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PersonForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            image = form.cleaned_data['image']
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']

            person = Person.objects.get(user=request.user)

            if image:
                person.image = form.cleaned_data['image']
            if name:
                person.name = form.cleaned_data['name']

            person.save() 
    return render(request,'edit.html',{'form': PersonForm()})
```

Answer (score 1):

django forms does validation on the users data

validation is done on two levels:

1. the field level:

   - if the field is required and the user didn't enter any data it will raise an error
   - if the user entered improperly formatted data for that field it will raise an error
   - you can override the behavior of field validation by implementing functions named as `clean_fieldname`
   - this type of validation results in `form.field.errors`
2. the form level:

   - checks for any (non-field specific) validation errors
   - you can override the behavior by implementing `clean` method
   - this type of validation results in `form.non_field_errors`

from your models:

image is not allowed to be blank which means it is required. not entering an image will raise an error

let blank=True for both name and image

also I recommend using [form.save()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) over saving models from the views

also there is a built in ImageField for saving images